# Is there a way to parallelize my pandas dataframe functions in airflow?

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I'm currently working on an academic project which requires the use of airflow. Currently, I'm only dealing with one database table therefore I require some assistance to know if I'm going in the correct direction.

I have a .py file called data_transformation.py:

```
def get_df_from_db():
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='HOST',
                                 user='USER',
                                 password='PW',
                                 database='DB')
    query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.drop('index', axis=1, inplace=True)
    connection.close()
    return df

def clean_colorTypes(df):
    df['colorType'] = df['colorType'].apply(lambda x: x if x in ['Red', 'Blue', 'Orange'] else 'Others')
    df = df[df['numOfButtons'] <= 2]
    return df

def add_yearsSinceManufactured(df):
    df['yearsSinceManu'] = df['yearListed'] - df['yearManufactured']
    return df

def add_to_db(df):
    #create connection to mysql using create_engine
    df.to_sql(name = 'cleaned', con = conn, if_exists = 'append', index = False)

    return df
```

My idea for my airflow dag file is:

1. execute get_df_from_db
2. execute clean_colorTypes and add_yearsSinceManufactured at the same time since they are not dependent
3. once step 2 is done, execute add_to_db

However, I'm not sure if this approach can be done since I am passing in df in every function.

Comment: I'd execute the logic on the database itself. Use Airflow to orchestrate the SQL calls, and have the database take on the load of actually manipulating the data

Comment: It's a requirement for doing ETL. Any ideas for using airflow?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the way it was already suggested, either:

- have the DB do all the heavy lifting, each query as a separate task, with staging tables in between, or;
- if you're adamant, use Pandas, save each transformation to a CSV.

Airflow DB (XCOM) is simply not suitable for holding large data, it is simply a feature for sending data from task to task.

The DB route would still be an ETL pipeline:

1. You extract the necessary data
2. Load it to your DB
3. Transform it however you want it

Comment: If so, how can I use airflow to orchestrate the SQL queries that I have written on python?